# pythonの画像処理module（Pillow）に関する質問です。

Tags: python, pillow

Pillowでスクリーンショットをとろうと、以下のコードを実行しました。ところが、パソコンの画面のx軸y軸ともに半分までしかキャプチャされません。縦横1000pxづつとすれば、画面の左上を開始位置として縦横500pxまでしかキャプチャされません。改善点教えていただければ幸いです
（ピクセルを指定しても結果は同じでした。予想では縦横半分までの領域を画面全体として認識しているようです）

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
def main():
    extraction=ImageGrab.grab()
    extraction.show()
    if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Windowsユーザーで本家SOで同じ問題に出会って解決した人がいました．
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370228/python-imaging-library-fails-to-grab-whole-screen
その人曰く

- Pythonの実行ファイルの存在するディレクトリを開く（例えばc:/python27/）
- python.exeを右クリックしてプロパティを選択
- 互換性タブを選択
- 全てのユーザーの設定を変更を押す
- 高DPI設定におけるディスプレイのスケーリングを無効化にチェックを入れる

以上の手順によりきちんと動作するようになるそうです．
試してみてください．